# Firebase C++ VS2018 SDL2 - exception trown on firebase::app::create(...)

Tags: android, c++, firebase, visual-studio-2008

**OS**: Win7 64,
**IDE**: Visual Studio Community 2018 (updated today)
**Clang**: 5.0
**Firebase Libs linked**:
firebase_cpp_sdk_5.2.1\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a
firebase_cpp_sdk_5.2.1\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_admob.a
**Target API Level**: KitKat 4.4 - 4.4.4, (android-19)
**STL**: LLVM libc++ static library (c++_static)
**C++ Standard**: C++17 (GNU Dialect) (-std=gnu++1z)
**Debug**: Nokia3 Nougat7.1

SDL2 compiled for android with the same settings.

Code issue:

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__

#include "firebase/admob.h"
#include "firebase/app.h"

firebase::App *app = NULL;

JNIEnv *env = (JNIEnv*)SDL_AndroidGetJNIEnv();
assert(env);

jobject activity = (jobject)SDL_AndroidGetActivity();

// unknown exception trown here
app = firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions(), env, activity);

#endif
```

callstack

```
libc.so!tgkill   
libc.so!pthread_kill   
libc.so!raise   
libc.so!__libc_android_abort   
libc.so!abort   
libmain.so!firebase::DefaultLogCallback(firebase::LogLevel log_level, const char * message) Line 66    C++  
libmain.so!firebase::LogMessageWithCallbackV(firebase::LogLevel log_level, const char * format) Line 130    C++  
libmain.so!firebase::LogAssert(const char * format) Line 174    C++  
libmain.so!firebase::util::LookupMethodIds(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, const firebase::util::MethodNameSignature * method_name_signatures, size_t number_of_method_name_signatures, jmethodID * method_ids, const char * class_name) Line 562    C++  
libmain.so!firebase::app::CacheMethodIds(JNIEnv * env, jobject activity_object) Line 46    C++  
libmain.so!firebase::(anonymous namespace)::CacheMethods(JNIEnv * env, jobject activity) Line 123    C++
libmain.so!firebase::App::Create(const firebase::AppOptions & options, const char * name, JNIEnv * jni_env, jobject activity) Line 305    C++
libmain.so!SDL_main(int argc, char ** argsv) Line 54    C++
libmain.so!Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jobject array) Line 67    C  
 [Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]
```

As far as I can see bot env and activity are valid objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update

Probably an issue with Visual Studio. 
Since firebase is not a standard SDK and depends on various google APIs and services that connects to google services real-time, VS encounters unpredictable situations and is unable to create a valid firebase:app object. This thus throws unknown and unhandled exception.

Pinpointing this follows to Android NDK being unable to correctly indentify google-services.json/xml definition for the app.

Manually specifing this definition with

```
firebase::AppOptions::LoadFromJsonConfig("google-services.json/xml");
```

generated the following error in the logcat

```
Failed to parse Firebase config: 1:0: error: declaration expected. Check the config string passed to App::CreateFromJsonConfig()
```

then, trying to call

```
 app = firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions(), env, activity);
```

Will generate the

```
firebase : E: Java class com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp not found.  Please verify the AAR which contains the com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp class is included in your app.
```

There is no difference if the .json file definitions are specified in the file, xml file, included in the strings.xml in the project file or the definitions are created on the stack and then passed as AppOption in the Create call.

The result is the same.

Anyone trying to do this, I suggest making a project in Android Studio with the preprocessor definitions referencing different VS and AS IDEs. And using the shared files.